# variable names are limited to 256 bytes

Tags: r, roxygen

roxygenize is failing on the following code with the following error message.  Other posts on this topic indicate that there's a misplaced character.  I can't find anything wrong!   Can you spot the issue?

```
#' My Title. My Description
#'
#' @return A n x n \code{\link{matrix}} where n = the number of variables.  Row and column names are in the same order and are equivalent to the variable names in \samp{timeSeriesData}.  Each entry [i,j] in the matrix is the covariance between variable i and variable j.
#' @callGraphPrimitives
#' @note some notes here
MyFunc = function( timeseriesData ,  method , decayFactor  )
{
}


Error in do.call(paste, c(trimmed.lines, sep = "\n")) :
  variable names are limited to 256 bytes
Calls: roxygenize ... parse.ref.list -> append -> parse.ref -> parse.ref.preref
-> do.call
Execution halted
```

**Edit1**
The above code works just fine if I take out a few words from the long @return line

**Edit2**
Adding sessionInfo() results before the roxygenize call.

```
R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  utils     datasets  grDevices methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] roxygen_0.1-2 digest_0.4.2
```

Comment: This runs without any errors on my machine.  What is the result of `sesionInfo()`?

Comment: I posted sessionInfo before the roxygenize call.  I can't get it to work after the roxygenize call because execution halts.  Note that the original code works fine if you take out a few words from the end of the @return line.

Comment: Here's a guess:  The `@return` paramater is limited to 256 characters.  Maybe I've come across the same problem in the past, because as a rule my `@return` contains something minimal like `@return data.frame`.  Instead, I tend to to use the roxygen description to expand on the mechanics and output.  FYI, you are missing the `@param` calls - if you intend to use this function in a package, the R CMD check will fall over if your @param and function parameters don't match.

Comment: @Andrie - yup, I took out the @param just to reduce the code.  I guess you're right about @return...it would be great to get a definitive answer that that is in fact a limition.

Comment: @Andrie - ah...just saw @Henry's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug: see [this discussion](https://github.com/ggobi/cranvas/issues/6) involving Hadley Wickham, a contributor to roxygen.

The work-round is to have shorter lines: your `#' @return A n x n ...` line has about 270 characters (including three sentences) in it, so could easily be split.

Comment: +1 also.  when you say "split" you mean that I can keep the content and just split it on multple lines?

Answer (score 2):

The other possible solution is upgrading to R2.13.0, now your character length has a max value of 10.000 instead of 256